# Can't run Rspec, spork , auto test on Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, rspec2, autotest, spork

Am working my way through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and am now in Chapter 5. However, I cannot get my Rspec, spark and auto tests to run. When I try to get them to run, I get an error message:

```
Paul-Denlingers-MacBook-Pro:sample_app_2 pdenlinger$ rspec spec/
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load': /Users/pdenlinger/rails_projects/sample_app_2/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `map'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
    from /Users/pdenlinger/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `block in autorun'
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

pages_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do


  it "should have a Home page at '/' do"
    get '/'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
  end

  it "should have a Contact page at '/contact' do"
    get '/contact'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
  end

  it "should have a About page at '/about' do"
    get '/about'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
  end

  it "should have a Help page at '/help' do"
    get '/help'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message, it looks like you have a missing `end` in this file:

```
spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb
```

at line 14.

---

**Update after @pdenlinger fixed his post:**

You are enclosing the `do` keyword in quotes when you shouldn't. It should look like this instead:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do
  it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
    get '/'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
  end

  it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
    get '/contact'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
  end

  it "should have a About page at '/about'" do
    get '/about'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
  end

  it "should have a Help page at '/help'" do
    get '/help'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
  end
end
```

Comment: That's strange; I couldn't find what was wrong with it. Have pasted in the code above.

Comment: Ok, I expanded the post with the necessary corrections. See above.

Answer (score 0):

All of your `do` keywords are enclosed in your example descriptions. Change:

```
it "should have a Home page at '/' do"
```

to:

```
it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
```

and repeat for each of your examples.